# libva version error on yocto build

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, intel, yocto

I was trying to build a Yocto Image for intel processor.

I downloaded the latest source code of poky and then clone the meta-intel branch and added it to bblayers.conf file.

```
git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-intel

MACHINE = "intel-core2-32"
```

I started build with the following command

```
bitbake core-image-sato
```

And got the following error:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (libva >= 1.1.0) were not met:
| 
| Requested 'libva >= 1.1.0' but version of libva is 0.40.0
| 
| Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
| installed software in a non-standard prefix.
|
```

I have the following recipe in this folder meta/recipes-graphics/libva/libva_1.8.3.bb

It means the version should be 1.8.3 instead of 0.4.0

Comment: Try cleaning and building libva again. and check the version in tmp/work/<machine>/libva/<verison> .......Use "bitbake libva -c cleanall && bitbake libva"

Comment: It is 1.8.3 and not 0.40.0

Comment: the solution is obvious: upgrade libva to 1.1.0+

Comment: It's already more than that.. why it is accepting as 0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of libva that configure is looking for (in some recipe you didn't name) is the API version. This is not necessarily the same as the package version. libva is one of the examples where package/recipe version and API version are not too related.

libva 1.x provides API version 0.y . Yes, it's weird.

Your real problem is here:

> I downloaded the latest source code of poky and then clone the
>   meta-intel branch

meta-intel is not a branch, it's a layer and git repo. If you did not specifically change the branch of that git repo, you are using master. This is typically not compatible with release versions of poky.

If you want to keep using the poky release you've downloaded, you must checkout the matching release branch/tag in meta-intel.

This is not required to fix your issue but I would suggest using git to get all of your layers, poky included. That way it's easy to pick the branches you want (and the method to do that is the same for all layers) and also easier to upgrade when e.g. there's a bug fix release to poky...